# Open Ipython notebook in a directory containing character like àèìòù

Tags: python, directory, ipython

Why I can't open Ipython notebook in this directory?

```
~/Documenti/Università
```

I think it is due to the character "à" but how can I solve this problem? Should really change of the directory? Here the output:

```
nunzio@nunzio-Lenovo-U310:~/Documenti/Università$ ipython notebook
[NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: 
--------------------------------------------------
more output
---------------------------------------------------
    value.instance_init(inst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py", line 243, in instance_init
    self.set_default_value(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py", line 263, in set_default_value
    newdv = self._validate(obj, dv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py", line 311, in _validate
    return self.validate(obj, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py", line 1012, in validate
    return unicode(value)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)

If you suspect this is an IPython bug, please report it at:
    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues
or send an email to the mailing list at ipython-dev@scipy.org

You can print a more detailed traceback right now with "%tb", or use "%debug"
to interactively debug it.

Extra-detailed tracebacks for bug-reporting purposes can be enabled via:
    c.Application.verbose_crash=True
```

The vesion of Ipython is 0.12.1

Comment: Works for me with Debian ipython 0.13.1-2

Comment: Ipython version 0.12.1, Sorry I give you few details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the version of Ipython to 0.13.1 and now works everything well.
Thank you to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This is an environment issue; I can reproduce the crash by issuing `env -i ipython` (IPython 0.13.1). The variable that prevents this from happening is `LANG`:

```
env -i LANG="$LANG" ipython
```

works. My setting for this is `en_US.UTF-8`, so you can add something like

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

to your `.bashrc`.

Comment: It is true, if I run `env -i ipython` the crash is reproduced, but adding the var `LANG` the crash doesn't happen, but actually the problem is with "ipython notebook" and this one return the same error even set the var `LANG`. Perhaps there is some problem with the my version of ipython.